# How to fix the promise anti pattern - Ghost Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

I found the term "The Ghost Promise" [here](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/), which looks like my case.

I have the code like this:

```
return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  firstFunctionThatReturnPromise()
  .then(function(firstResult) {
    _check(firstResult) ? resolve(firstResult) : return secondFunctionThatReturnPromise();
  })
  .then(function(secondResult) {
    console.log(secondResult);
    return thirdFunctionThatReturnPromise(secondResult);
  })
  .then(function(thirdResult) {
    resolve(thirdResult);
  })
  .catch(function(e) {
    reject(e)
  });
});
```

The problem is, even though the `_check` returns true, it still proceeds to the `console.log` command (which results in `undefined`).

In case the `_check` returns false, things work as expected.

So my question is:

- If the behavior described above is normal?
- If there is a more elegant way to handle this case?

**Update 1:** Many questioned that why I use `Q.Promise` instead of returning the result directly. It's because this is a generic function, shared by other functions.

```
// Usage in other functions
genericFunction()
.then(function(finalResult) {
   doSomething(finalResult);
})
.catch(function(err) {
   handleError(err);
});
```

Comment: You don't have a ghost here, but a plain [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there's no reason to wrap a new promise around any of this.  Your operations already return promises so it is an [error prone anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) to rewrap them in a new promise.

Second off, as others have said, a `.then()` handler has these choices:

1. It can return a result which will be passed to the next `.then()` handler.  Not returning anything passes `undefined` to the next `.then()` handler.
2. It can return a promise whose resolved value will be passed to the next `.then()` handler or rejected value will be passed to the next reject handler.
3. It can throw which will reject the current promise.

There is no way from a `.then()` handler to tell a promise chain to conditionally skip some following `.then()` handlers other than rejecting.

So, if you want to branch your promise based on some condition logic, then you need to actually **nest your `.then()` handlers according to your branching logic**:

```
a().then(function(result1) {
    if (result1) {
        return result1;
    } else {
        // b() is only executed here in this conditional
        return b().then(...);
    }
}).then(function(result2) {
    // as long as no rejection, this is executed for both branches of the above conditional
    // result2 will either be result1 or the resolved value of b()
    // depending upon your conditional
})
```

So, when you want to branch, you make a new nested chain that lets you control what happens based on the conditional branching.

Using your psuedo-code, it would look something like this:

```
firstFunctionThatReturnPromise().then(function (firstResult) {
    if (_check(firstResult)) {
        return firstResult;
    } else {
        return secondFunctionThatReturnPromise().then(function (secondResult) {
            console.log(secondResult);
            return thirdFunctionThatReturnPromise(secondResult);
        })
    }
}).then(function (finalResult) {
    console.log(finalResult);
    return finalResult;
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
});
```

Even if this is inside a genericFunction, you can still just return the promise you already have:

```
function genericFunction() {
    return firstFunctionThatReturnPromise().then(function (firstResult) {
        if (_check(firstResult)) {
            return firstResult;
        } else {
            return secondFunctionThatReturnPromise().then(function (secondResult) {
                console.log(secondResult);
                return thirdFunctionThatReturnPromise(secondResult);
            })
        }
    }).then(function (finalResult) {
        console.log(finalResult);
        return finalResult;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    });
}

// usage
genericFunction().then(...).catch(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edit my question to add the reason I use promise wrapper.

Comment: @haipham23 - I still don't see any reason to wrap this in a promise.  You don't seem to understand that you don't need to make a new promise in order to return it.  You can just return the one you already have as my answer shows.

Comment: Thanks, I follow your instruction above and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is expected. When you chain your `.then()` statements, you cannot break out of the chain early except by throwing an error.

Your top-level promise (the one returned by `Q.Promise()`) gets resolved after `_check()`; but you actually have an inner promise chain that continues to execute.

By specification, `then()` returns a promise: https://promisesaplus.com/#point-40

You can see for yourself in the source code of Q: https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/q.js#L899

For your desired behavior, you'll actually need another nested promise chain.

```
return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  firstFunctionThatReturnPromise().then(function(firstResult) {
    if (_check(firstResult)) {
      resolve(firstResult);
    } else {
      return secondFunctionThatReturnPromise().then(function(secondResult) {
        console.log(secondResult);
        return thirdFunctionThatReturnPromise(secondResult);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Given that all functions already return promises, there's no need to wrap them with `Q.Promise`. Just return the promise returned by `firstFunctionThatReturnPromise` (and plainly return `firstResult`, as it will be wrapped automatically).

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Q, but everything a promise returns is transformed into a promise and passed to the next `.then()`. Here, your first `.then()` don't return anything. So it returns `undefined`. So `undefined` is wrapped in a new `Promise` and passed to the next handler, where you get `secondResult == undefined`.

You can see it in action in the following CodePen : http://codepen.io/JesmoDrazik/pen/xOaXKE